# How can I put files into subdirectories based on the name of the file using bash?

Tags: bash

I am trying to take a directory filled with an unknown number of files and put each file into a subdirectory based on the name of the file. A file's name could have multiple subdirectories in it all separated by the underscore character so it needs to be able to recursively extract subdirectory names.

**Example Files:**

```
2020_Documents_Bills_Water Bill.pdf
2020_Documents_Taxes_W2.pdf
2020_Documents_Receipts_Store Name_Groceries.pdf
2020_Pictures_Family Trip_California_Disney Land_Family Pic.jpg
```

So the `2020_Documents_Bills_Water Bill.pdf` file would end up as `2020/Documents/Bills/Water Bill.pdf`.

*I would like to limit the tools used to bash, sed, grep, mkdir, and mv if possible.*

I had some thoughts on how I believe the script should flow, but I don't know how to make it recursively get subdirectories without a lot of yucky **if** statements. I was thinking this code could probably get the first subdir and put it in an array and then remove that text and the underscore that follows it from the name of the file and then iterate again until it runs out of underscores.

```
#!/bin/bash

# cd to directory where files are located
cd /directory/with/files

# iterate over files in directory
for file in *; do
  subDirs=() # empty array for subdirs
  filePath="" # empty string to build filepath

  # ------------------------------------------------------------
  # code to extract subdir names and add to subDirs array
  # ------------------------------------------------------------

  # build filepath using string of all subdirs
  for i in ${!subDirs[@]}; do
    filepath="${filePath}/${subDirs[$i]}"
  done

  # set filename to text after last underscore
  filename=${file##*_}

  # make filepath based on subdirs
  mkdir -p "${filepath}"

  # move file into filepath without subdirs in name
  mv ${file} "${filepath}/${filename}"

done
```

Comment: Id add a `cd /directory/with/files || exit` so you will not get unexpected results, like renaming /moving files in a directory that is not intended to run your script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it simpler because `mkdir -p path/to/yours` works just with one invocation. You do not have to recursively create subdirectories one by one.
Would you please try:

```
cd /directory/with/files        # cd to directory where files are located

for file in *; do
    [[ -f $file ]] || continue  # skip non-file entries (just in case)
    dir=${file%_*}
    base=${file##*_}

    dir=${dir//_/\/}            # replace "_"s with "/"s
    mkdir -p "$dir"
    mv -- "$file" "$dir/$base"
done
```

**[Strict Version]**
The script below performs the validation of the filenames (with a help of jhnc).

```
for file in *; do
    [[ -f $file ]] || continue  # skip non-file entries (just in case)
    dir=${file%_*}
    base=${file##*_}

    dir=${dir//_//}             # replace "_"s with "/"s

    # validate filenames
    case "/$dir/" in
        */../* | */./* | //*)   # $dir contains extra dot(s)
            echo "skipping invalid filename: $file"
            continue
            ;;
    esac
    if [[ -z $base ]]; then     # the filename ends with "_"
        echo "skipping invalid filename: $file"
        continue
    fi

    mkdir -p "$dir"
    mv -- "$file" "$dir/$base"
done
```

Result:

```
/directory/
└── with
    └── files
        └── 2020
            ├── Documents
            │   ├── Bills
            │   │   └── Water Bill.pdf
            │   ├── Receipts
            │   │   └── Store Name
            │   │       └── Groceries.pdf
            │   └── Taxes
            │       └── W2.pdf
            └── Pictures
                └── Family Trip
                    └── California
                        └── Disney Land
                            └── Family Pic.jpg
```

Comment: should also test for `..` as subpath of `$dir`

Comment: @jhnc thank you for the comment, but sorry, I don't get it. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @tshiono This is exactly what I was looking for. I knew there must be an easier way to do it than what I was thinking. Thank you! You are amazing.

Comment: @tshiono If the filename were to be, for example, `a_b_.._c_d` then the folder would become `a/b/../c` which is a security concern.

Comment: @jhnc thanks for your suggestion. If I'm understanding correctly, the possible risk
is a `directory traversal attack` overwriting files as
`../../../../etc/passwd` (if ran with a root privilege).
I've updated my code accordingly. BR.

Comment: @tshiono yes, that's the issue. I think the `${dir//_//}` is safe. You could avoid the sed overhead by testing, for example, `dir=${dir//_//}; case "/$dir/" in */../* | */./* | //*) : warning ;; *) : normal code ;; esac`

Comment: There's another potential issue if the filename has form `a_` (ends with underscore) -  it's not clear what the rewriting should produce.

Comment: @jhnc thanks again. I've split into the original version and the strict one to clarify the difference.

Comment: `or is empty`: Actually my `//*` was supposed to check for absolute paths (`_etc_passwd`, etc). Maybe just `*//*` instead of `*/./* | //*` is simpler (as `.` is not dangerous although could indicate an inappropriate file to move)

Comment: Oh I see. Let me correct the comment in the code. As for the filename which starts with a dot, it will not be included in the `for file in *` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Just one note to add `cd /directory/with/files`

Without the `exit` . Assuming `/directory/with/files` does not exists.

```
#!/bin/bash

# cd to directory where files are located
cd /directory/with/files

printf '%s\n' 'rm this' 'rm that' 'mv this' 'mv that'
```

the output is

```
myscript: line 4: cd: /directory/with/files: No such file or directory
rm this
rm that
mv this
mv that
```

all the code after the `cd` is/was still executed!

With the `exit` and assuming the `/directory/with/files` does not exists.

```
#!/bin/bash

# cd to directory where files are located
cd /directory/with/files || exit

printf '%s\n' 'rm this' 'rm that' 'mv this' 'mv that'
```

The output.

```
myscript: line 4: cd: /directory/with/files: No such file or directory
```

The script did exit and it did not execute the rest of the code.